# Cant get value from input field

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have an input field with datetime-local type, on editing the form, I cant get the value (which is datetime). In UI, it has the ----- --:--, but when inspecting the code, VALUE parameter has data

Ive tried to document.getElementById().value, $().val(), $().text(), but all of them return "" (empty)

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="date-from" required="required" value="2019-08-20 05:11:00 UTC" name="pass_request[date_from]">
document.getElementById('date-from').value === ""
$('#date-from').val() === ""
$('#date-from').text() === ""
```

I value to return, but not emptiness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should format your value according to [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#page-6) as written here - https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#form.data.datetime-local

> ```
> The following parts, in exactly the following order:
> A date.
> The literal string "T".
> A time.
> ```

> Example:
> 1985-04-12T23:20:50.52
> 1996-12-19T16:39:57

So try

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="date-from" name="pass_request[date_from]" value="2015-02-15T03:35:00">
```

Comment: thanks! it works now, didnt know that its so strict